# Preserving the notion of inheritance in a REST-based web-app

Tags: javascript, rest, inheritance

We are building a new Single-Page frontend to replace the old static html frontend (with some jquery) of our web-app. While doing so we run into a problem concerning the type of objects we get back from the api.

When exporting data as JSON from our PHP backend we include an extra field in which we put the type the object had before exporting. We can use this to handle different subclasses of the resource we requested.

However sometimes we would also like to differentiate on parent classes. Consider the following scenario:

Inheritance tree:

```
Animal
    Mammal
        Human
        Dog
        ...
    Reptile
        Crocodile
        Snake
        ...
```

GET /animals/

```
[
    {"_type": "Human", "id": 1, "food": "Ice Cream"},
    {"_type": "Human", "id": 2, "food": "Steak"},
    {"_type": "Human", "id": 3, "food": "Peanut Butter"},
    {"_type": "Dog", "id": 4, "food": "Horse Poop"}
    {"_type": "Crocodile", "id": 5, "food": "Humans"}
]
```

When I have a certain piece of UI in which I would like to display all the animals but for instance highlight all the mammals I have a problem because I have lost the knowledge which animals are mammals.

The easiest solution we have come up with is to include the inheritance chain when exporting the objects from our backend. Possibly like this:

```
{
    "_type": "Human",
    "id": 10,
    "food": "Ice Cream",
    "_parentClasses": "Animal.Mammal.Human"
}
```

While I don't consider this a particularly nice solution it is easy to implement and use and seems robust.

Do you think this is a good/ok/bad idea and how have you tackled this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options. Here is one that I haven't seen mentioned:

Make your `_type` an array instead of a string, with the first item containing the current class and the rest parent classes.

```
{
    "_type": ["Human","Mammal","Animal"],
    "id": 10,
    "food": "Ice Cream"
}
```

This should be easy to implement on the PHP side with this:

```php
$_type = array_keys(class_parents($this));
array_unshift($_type, get_class($this));
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the very thing that is causing your heartache is the flattening of your objects on output.  Perhaps GET/Animals should return something more like the following:

```
[
    {"Mammals": {   
        {"_type": "Human", "id": 1, "food": "Ice Cream"},
        {"_type": "Human", "id": 2, "food": "Steak"},
        {"_type": "Human", "id": 3, "food": "Peanut Butter"},
        {"_type": "Dog", "id": 4, "food": "Horse Poop"}
    },
    {"Reptiles": {
        {"_type": "Crocodile", "id": 5, "food": "Humans"}
    }
]
```

If you can preserve the structure of your objects on output, when you send that complex object back to the server your structure should remain intact.

Comment: I could do this, but that would not be an accurate representation of the dataset (which is a simple list) an would make it difficult to work with (looping over all the elements would take more code and even require knowledge of how many levels this structure has).

Comment: @martijnve What that tells me is that if it is a simple list, it is not preserving the relationships correctly in the first place.  Perhaps a refactor is in order.  I typically serialize my entire complex object structure to my JSON payload, preserving the order.  I unfortunately do not know how difficult this would be in php, but I imagine there are good JSON serializers for complex objects.  My concern is that if you are working off of a "flat" list, the structure has already been compromised

Comment: The the structure is, and is supposed to be, a list. My backend has knowledge of the types of the objects and their inheritance. The problem is getting that information to the client in an easy way that doesn't involve any hard-coding.

In PHP its just an array of Animals on which i can do an instanceOf test whenever I need to know if a certain animal in my list is a Mammal.

Comment: @martijnve It's impossible for me to either agree with your or disagree without seeing more of the backend structure of course :).  That said, it seems dangerous to flatten an object while simultaneously expecting it to have knowledge of its parent types.  You may have to implement some referential lookup tables in your database that map your object types to their parent types.  That may be the only way to define the relationship while still having a "flat" output. I'd still argue for a refactor that preserves the inherited structure but either would work I think.

Comment: Maybe the problem is easier to understand if I put it in pseudo-java code: lets say i have the following: List<Animal> animals = SomeORM.get("animals"); - Now I can iterate over this list and do A if the animal is a Mammal and do B for all other animals. When I transport the list to my client over my API I end up with the same list but have lost the ability to distinguish Mammals from other Classes (pun intended) of Animals.

Comment: Ahh, I understand.  I think it's that initial iteration where it gets lost in tranlation, so to speak.  You could stick another property on your object called "Class".  That would denote the parent type.  Not elegant but it would work.

Answer (score 1):

Many good answers, here's another option you might want to think about.

You only send the subclass to the client in JSON, the client then does a lookup whatever its baseclasses are. It moves some complexity from the serverside to the clientside and you keep your JSON messages clean.

Answer (score 0):

I can see several ways of possibly achieving this. You could develop your REST server to accept URIs such as:

```
/animals/mammal/humans 
/animals/mammal/dog
/animals/reptile/crocodile
```

Or, simply return the type of object as you have stated above. Build the object off of the type.

```
<?php
    $object = null;     

    switch($_type){
      case 'human':
          $object = new Human();
      break;

      case 'dog':
          $object = new Dog();
      break;

      case 'crocodile':
        $object = new Crocodile();
      break;
    }
?>
```

Just my two cents on how I may solve this problem.

Comment: This does not solve my problem because i want to fetch (and use) the complete list, but still need to know which superclasses an object has.

Comment: I just updated my post, you will probably want to use something similar to the PHP code above.

Comment: @ilikemypizza I strongly dislike your updated approach.  This requires a hardcoded relationship between type and parent, or a relationship inferred by a database lookup.  This is probably not an elegant solution.

Comment: David, thanks for the feedback. I need to work the logic out, but it should be something along the lines of..

try {
  $object = new $_type;
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
//Exception Handler
}

Comment: The client is in JavaScript, not PHP and I would like the client logic to be as light weight (and require as little knowledge) as possible.

Comment: @martijnve - Now I understand. I am no expert, but javascript technically does not use classes or inheritance out of the box. It really depends on what your client application needs to do with this list. If it is simply just a list, is OOP necessary on the client side?

Comment: @ilikemypizza You are correct, it does not.  That said, it does have a hierarchical object structure which can represent server side classes.  It's something worth looking into when you have time :).

Comment: @likemypizza - i have no real need for inheritance on the client side. Except the need to know parent classes of objects in my list.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this qualifies an as answer, really (or even that the question qualifies as a question!!), but I used a similar process on a time manager a few years back; the inheritance paths done in a similar way.  I found it extremely easy and more intuitive to work with than some of the alternatives which would basically cause far more work down the line.

To extend the simplicity I also kind of broke the normal rules of OOP by allowing not only the parent to know the children, but also the children to know the parent.  It does add a little to the code but it's workable, and, again, makes the whole process less painful.